# Find combinations which do not have elements in common

Tags: php, algorithm, math, combinations, probability

I have array(A, B, C, D).

I choose 2 letters from above 4 letters in 6 combinations using combination formula

n! / r! (n-r)!

array(A, B),
array(A, C),
array(A, D),
array(B, C),
array(B, D),
array(C, D)

How can I find combinations of groups of 2 or 3 or n (should be dynamic) which do not have letters in common. So I am expecting result to be below combinations for group of 2,

array(A, B),
array(C, D)

array(A, C),
array(B, D),

array(A, D),
array(B, C),

This is just an example but i want the algorithm should work for large number of arrays (I have more than 35000 arrays). I want to find group of 2  or 3 or n (should be dynamic), each group should have arrays which do not have elements in common (all keys should be different, not a single elements should be repeated).

Answer (score 2):

You don't say anything about how the sets are represented, so I use arrays for that purpose.

```
// The base set
$baseSet = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');

// Build the subsets
$subSets = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j< 4; $j++) {
        $subSets[] = array($baseSet[$i], $baseSet[$j]);
    }
}
```

With that, the solution is straight forward:

```
foreach ($subSets as $subSet) {
    $complement = array_diff($baseSet, $subSet);
    printf("{%s, %s} - {$s, %s}\n",
        $baseSet[0], $baseSet[1],
        $complement[0], $complement[1]
    );
}
```

In general, PHP offers a lot of [set related functions for arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

If you just want to compare two subsets, use `array_intersect()`:

```
$common = array_intersect($subSet1, $subSet2);
if (empty($common)) {
    echo 'The subsets are distinct.';
} else {
    echo 'The subsets have these elements in common: ' . implode(', ', $common);
}
```

Comment: It works fine for small array but is there any way to handle large array ? I have array of size 9845. I want to find out unique combinations.

Comment: Added a comparision example to my answer.

Comment: It works for smaller number of array but when we have large number of arrays and having more array elements then it does not work.

Comment: 'Does not work' means ...? The comparision I suggested takes two out of *any* number of arrays.

Comment: Logic is correct, but nested for loops goes take long time to execute for huge number of combinations.